# Pandas: duplicate row by splitting the value of one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Chris Iannetta', 'John Hicks'], 'Pos':['C', 'C/1B'], 'HR':[12, 4]})
```

I want:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Chris Iannetta', 'John Hicks', 'John Hicks'], 'Pos':['C', 'C', '1B'], 'HR':[12, 4, 4]})
```

Thanks!